# How to write static classes in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am porting [JSON5 to dart](https://pub.dev/packages/json5), and I want to keep the original convention.

The original code has a `static class JSON5` which contains 2 static methods. But dart doesn't allow static classes.

My dart code:

```dart
/// static class, do not instanciate or inherit this
class JSON5 {
  static String stringify(dynamic obj) { };
  static dynamic parse(String json5String) { };
}
```

Is it possible to stop users from 2 things?

- instanciate the class: `var json5 = JSON5()`
- extends or implements the class: `class DerivedJSON5 extends JSON5 {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disallow instantiation you can add a private constructor: `JSON5._();`

And to prevent inheritance the best you can currently do in dart is adding the `@sealed` annotation from the [meta](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) package

Comment: +1, JSON5._() does hide the default constructor . But @sealed is still not working, I have tried to run `dartnalyzer  lib` without success. maybe it needs a configuration file. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why that's not working, but I wouldn't worry too much about being able to inherit from it since static members cannot be inherited so it basically doesnt do anything